# how can i use UIDatePicker in iPad on Landscape mode?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I am showing a UIDatePicker on a universal app. On iPhone it shows fine, on iPad it shows only the bottom portion.
This is my code:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
        pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

        UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 0,0)];
        pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        pickerView.hidden = NO;
        pickerView.date = [NSDate date];
        [pickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,64)];
        pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
        [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

        NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
        [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
        [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

        UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];
        [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

        [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
        [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];
        [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerView];
        [pickerViewPopup showInView:self.view];
        [pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,1024, 768)];

    }
```

Comment: you need to use UIPopoverController instead of action sheet in case of ipad

Comment: Ok thanx.But do you have any example?

Comment: Try to change this line  [pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,1024, 768)]; // change the setBounds method to setFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used that code and it's working

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
            UIViewController *popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
            UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
            popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
            datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
            datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
            datePicker.hidden = NO;
            datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
            [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
           [popoverView addSubview:datePicker];
            popoverContent.view = popoverView;
            popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 200);
            UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1150,480) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```